# ((MyCustomObject)myObjectType).MyProperty has a huge cost?

Tags: c#, casting

Well, I have in my model an ObservableCollection of type object in this way:

```
private ObservableCollection<object> _selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();
public SelectedItems
{
    get{return _selectedItems}
    set
    {
        _selectedItems = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItems");
    }
}
```

I am using a attached property to update the selected items from the view, so to do it a generic behavior that use the object type.

Well, my problem is that in my view model I need to access of the properties of my type. So I am doing this:

```
((MyCustomType)SelectedItems[0]).MyProperty.
```

But this is a very tedious work and think that this cast has a cost. So I am doing this many times, I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Perhaps to use a dynamic type instead of a object type? The advantage is that I don't need to do the cast, but I lost the intellisense feature, so it is more difficult to debug errors.

Perhaps another solution?

Comment: If you know its `MyCustomObject` why isnt the collection `ObservableCollection<MyCustomObject>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting without boxing/unboxing (So assuming `MyCustomObject` is a class not a struct)  does not have a particularly huge overhead, but the correct solution if you know that the type is always `MyCustomObject` is to declare the collection as

```
private ObservableCollection<MyCustomObject> _selectedItems 
                        = new ObservableCollection<MyCustomObject>();
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am trying to craete a generic behavior and I can use MyCustomObject as type, but then I can't reuse the behavior. If I use the object type I can reuse it, but I have to cast every elemet that I want to use. I would like to use MyCustomObject, but I don't find the way.